# Rails - json - password appearing in json response with except defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jbuilder

I am having an issue getting the json I get in the response in my rails app.  I've tried using an as_json method in model, I've tried using an only statement in a jbuilder file in the views folder, but no matter what I do the password (the hashed version of it) still shows up in the returned json.  I believe I was doing the steps correctly but was not able to find the root cause of this.  any suggestions would be appreciated.  Also, when I tried the as_json method in the model options I got some strange error that included a large spit out of the javascript from the rails framework, so that is another side issue blocking me from using that option.  Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: paste some code `user[somerandomnumberhere]`

Comment: Show code and error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the issue.  I misremembered that in my rails app the password was stored under an attribute named "password_digest"  not the "password" I thought it was and had used in the "as_json" method def.  I have the expected output from as_json now.  did not retry the other approach of using the jbuilder file.